# Is there a way to implement early stopping in Keras ONLY after the first, say, 100 epochs

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

My fit function is nonconvex so that the loss function can sometimes worsen before it improves. Given this, I want to use early stopping, but only after the first 100 or more epochs. So far I have this:

```
# Early stopping
ES = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=100,verbose=1,mode='auto')]

# fit model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000,batch_size=50,verbose=2,shuffle=True,validation_split=.1,callbacks=ES)
```

Unfortunately, the fit stops very early after 10 or so epochs. I want to wait until the 100th epoch to start early stopping. Any ideas? Any suggestions other than early stopping are also appreciated.

Comment: Is there a line like "Epoch 10: early stopping" in the output? If not, it's not the callback that's terminating training. Because with patience=100, it really should wait for at least those 100 epochs (see its implementation at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L486)

Comment: Also, couldn't you call `model.fit(epochs=100, ..., callbacks=[])` without the ES callbacks, and then call `model.fit(epochs=900, ..., callbacks=ES)`?

Comment: I like this idea. Seems to work pretty well without complicating the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use `patience=100` your training should not stop before epoch 100. However, if you want to have a short `patience` but also want it to start later, you could use the method described by colllin. If you want further customization, you can always define your own callback, here with `EarlyStopping` as a parent. For your purposes you just need to override the initializer and the `on_epoch_end` method found [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L431):

```py
class CustomStopper(keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping):
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss',
             min_delta=0, patience=0, verbose=0, mode='auto', start_epoch = 100): # add argument for starting epoch
        super(CustomStopper, self).__init__()
        self.start_epoch = start_epoch

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch > self.start_epoch:
            super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
```

You only have to give the earliest epoch from where you want to monitor your criterion to the initializer and check the condition before calling the function from the parent class.

Comment: Very cool. So, to understand this correctly, the new inherited class, CustomStopper, adds a variable start_epoch (as seen in the __init__ method). Then, the new on_epoch_end statement says to use the base class' version of on_epoch_end if the current epoch is > start_epoch? Sorry but I am new to this and don't quite understand the super() statement.

Comment: @kchow462 Yes. Thats correct: `super()` calls the function of the parent class. So the result is that you can have a short patience, but the checking if the results get better starts only after a given number of epochs.

Comment: I dont know how it works in python2 but I am using python3 and I need to use super(CustomStopper, self).__init__(monitor=monitor,patience=patience,min_delta=min_delta,mode=mode) for my arguments to be passed to parent class. Otherwise it just uses the default arguments

Answer (score 3):

In version 2.13.1 you can use the parameter `start_from_epoch=100` in `tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping`. The tracking of the Early Stopping criterion will then start after the given epoch.
See: [early_stopping](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34719126)